# Trying to create function to count number of checked cells and call it from another function

Tags: iphone, objective-c, function, uitableview, methods

So I created a function:

```
-(void)checkCount:(UITableView *)tableView isIndexPathChecked:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] init];
UITableViewCell *investigatedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
if(investigatedCell.accessoryType ==UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
    name = investigatedCell.textLabel.text;
[checkedRows addObject: name];
}
```

I'm getting errors every time I try to call this method from within another method.  What would be the proper syntax for this?  Thank you.

Comment: What kind of errors you get would be useful to know.. Also where do you declare and initialize `checkedRows`?

Comment: One error that I keep getting is it says:  Use of undeclared identifier 'isIndexPathChecked' when I try to call it from another method.  And checkedRows is a property in my header file synthesized in the implementation

Comment: Did you initialize `checkedRows`? Otherwise it's just `nil`. Are you trying to call `checkCount:isIndexPathChecked:` from a method below it? In that case you have to predeclare it in the header or the implementation.

Comment: Yes, I initialized checkedRows.  And the method is declared in the header file and defined in the implementation file.  Also, if it makes a difference, the method checkCount:isIndexPathChecked: is the last method in my file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the error you are seeing is because the method call is not present in your public header file.  Try adding

```
-(void)checkCount:(UITableView *)tableView isIndexPathChecked:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

to your .h file.

You might also want to double-check your spelling and be absolutely sure you're sending the method call to the correct object.  I'm guessing self.

```
UITableView *myTable = pointer_to_tableView_instance;
NSIndexPath *indexPath = pointer_to_indexPath_to_check;
[self checkCount:myTable isIndexPathChecked:indexPath];
NSLog(@"%i",checkedRows.count);
```

Comment: If it's a private method, it shouldn't be added to the header file. Instead it can be added in the implementation file as a class extension.

Comment: I have the method declared in my header file.  I'm just not sure how to call it in my implementation file.  When I click a button, I want the method to be called, so in the pressButton method I want to have it call my custom method.

Comment: [self checkCount:myTable isIndexPathChecked:indexPath];